# Binary mask for output vector in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, bitmask

I want to recommend products by clickstream with LSTM in TensorFlow.

I have historical **user behaviour data** using which I want to use to train model to recommend products (represented as classes on output) but I need to consider whether product was active in that moment on webpage(not to recommend inactive deals).

Since I consider this very difficult using ground truth, I would like to use **binary mask on output** before it is compared to the **target vector**.

Is there any native way to do this in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tf.boolean_mask` on the softmax prediction output to remove the probabilities for inactive deals then get the maximum probabilities without them.